# Clarification on result of a probability question

Tags: probability

I am studying for a test and this is a practice exam question. I have the answer but I don't know how I get there.

A student is trying a new study strategy for the final exam. There
are four topics to study for the exam and each day he picks a topic at random to study (and so
he may study the same topic multiple times).

Let $T$ be the random variable corresponding to the
number of days he’ll study before he has studied every topic.

What are the values of the following probabilities?
$$P(T = 3) $$

$$P(T = 4)$$

The first answer is 0, while the second is $\frac {3}{32}$

My first instinct was to use Binomial but it seems I was way off.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well $\mathbb{P}(T=3)=0$ because there is no way for him to study $4$ topics in $3$ nights. How many ways are there for him to study $4$ different topics in $4$ nights? This is the number of ways to arrange the $4$ topics into $4$ nights: $4!$. Then divide this by the total number of ways he could study on the four nights: $4^4$ (he has four choices every night).